# Lack of native contextmenu handling in OpenLayers 3+?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, contextmenu, openlayers

As one of the burdened programmers struggling to upgrade an OL2 mapping app to OL4/5, I have been grateful to stackoverflow contributors whose postings/answers have resolved most of my issues. One remains: contextmenu handling.

I can't find any way of natively handling a contextmenu/right click in OL4+. I have, however, successfully used the excellent add-on by jonatawalker [here](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-contextmenu). This resource is a bit of an overkill (basically I just want to detect a right click and take action) and would prefer to stick to standards where possible. Have I missed something in the OL library?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a listener on the map canvas worked for version 5 and earlier versions, and up to 6.2 using the controls container worked, so this code was compatible with both versions

```
var canvas = map.getViewport().getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0] ||
             map.getViewport().getElementsByClassName("ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent")[0];

canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    ...
    ...
});
```

In version 6.3 that is not working, it seems to be the topmost canvas which is responsive, but canvases will change depending on layer visibility and view rotation.

Comment: THANK YOU!
I know I'm not the most skilled OpenLayers coder and when I saw your solution thought "Really? I've no idea what that's all about, but I'll give it a go."
The rightclick detection worked, but when I translated (getCoordinateFromPixel) the returned pixel coords (e.x,e.y) to map coords, the results weren't correct. Long story short, I peeked into the event data and spotted a few x,y alternatives. When I settled on e.layerX,elayerY (obvious now) I was home and dry.
Your guidance is much appreciated. Euge!